# Python unittest call and unexpected program run

Tags: python, unit-testing

Let's say i have a simple python program and a simple test file

iseven.py:

```
import math

def is_even(n):
    return n%2==0

print is_even(2)
print is_even(3)
```

and test_iseven.py:

```
import unittest
from iseven import is_even

class IsevenTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        self.assertTrue(is_even(2))
        self.assertFalse(is_even(3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Is there a difference in running the tests between

```
python test_iseven.py
```

and

```
python -m unittest test_iseven.py
```

? Because I've seen both in guides and tutorials, and output is identical. Also: The test is just for that one function, yet the whole program is executed when running the tests, so I get the program's output in the console. That is not supposed to happen, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference between ...?

There is no big difference when it comes to executing the tests.

The main difference is that in the latter case, you can omit the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

but you have to type more on the command line every time you want to run the tests.

So I prefer the first solution.

> Python executes the whole program.

The behavior is correct. To be able to import `is_even` from the module `iseven`, Python has to parse the whole module. It can't really just look at the function.

Since Python is a scripting language, parsing the module means that it has to execute all the commands in it. From Python's point of view, `def` is a command like `print` which creates a  new function instance and adds it to the current scope.

Or to put it differently: If it wouldn't run the `print`, it also couldn't run the `def`.

This behavior is often used to do magic. For example, in my i18n module for Python, I use:

```
@i18n
def name(): pass
```

At runtime, I collect all functions decorated with `@i18n` and turn them into code which checks the current language, loads the correct text from the translation file and returns it. That means I can do later:

```
print name()
```

and it will do the right thing.

**EDIT** Now you may have code in your module that you want to execute only when the module is run as a "program" (i.e. not when it's imported from somewhere else). Here is how you can do that:

```
def is_even(n):
    return n%2==0

def main():
    print is_even(2)
    print is_even(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

General recipe: Always move all code into functions; avoid keeping anything at the "root" level of the module.

Comment: Well ok, thanks for the great answer.The second part is still annoying since it displays existing prints and means long runtime for a simple unit test if the main program does some number crunching. Also this is never mentioned in the videos :x